# How to remove WooCommerce Plugin some specific features

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to know how I can remove some features in WooCommerce Plugin, I mean Add to Cart Button, My Account page, Cart page, Checkout Options, etc?

I only need to show the Shop page in my project and all other stuff needs to be hidden in the theme.

How I can archive this?

Comment: If you just wants a product list, you can achieve that in few different ways, without even using woocommerce

Comment: product catalog plugins will work with premium themes? will give me good design? that is my problem

Comment: wasn't talking about using a catalog plugin. use page template and if you have a visual builder, you can use it to make a grid, if not you can use custom fields and use your own styling in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable Membership:**

Uncheck box under 'Wordpress - Settings - General ~ Membership'.

Uncheck boxes under 'WooCommerce - Settings - Accounts & Privacy'.

**Add the following code to your `functions.php` file to remove the 'Add to Cart' button:**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

**To redirect away from the cart or checkout page:**

Select a page for the Cart and Checkout pages under 'WooCommerce - Settings - Advanced ~ Page Setup'.

Comment: After checking those on my side, I will approve this answer. thank you